# How to force Scala Version for Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark Reference states the following :

> For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.4 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x).
>   **Support for Scala 2.11 is deprecated as of Spark 2.4.1** and will be removed in Spark 3.0.

However, with a fresh Spark 2.4.4 default install (using PyPi) I somehow got it bundled with Scala 2.11, as you can see in the pic.

[image: force]

So : ***Why is that, and how to force it to 2.12 ?***

(I really googled and looked in the doc but I'm missing it)

***EDIT :***
FYI I installed Spark by running `pip install pyspark` as advised on the official DL page.
As Spark uses the Scala version which has been used to compile it, i suspect that the version in the pip repo is not up to date. But then why compile Spark 2.4.4 with a deprecated version of Scala then ? I'm confused.

Comment: **Spark** `2.4.4` is compatible with both **Scala** `2.11` & `2.12`. It will use the one which was used to to compile it. Most distributions are using **Scala** `2 11` as it is the most common one. If you are interested in just **pyspark** I would not worry about that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Good point. I edited the reference quote to reflect the fact that 2.11 is deprecated as of Spark 2.4.1, hence my concern. Also, I am prototyping in pyspark but deploying in production in Scala, and I did build my code on 2.12 as advised, so it actually does matter in my case, practically speaking, I was not just being picky

Comment: While it is deprecated it is still the most used one. If you still would like to use `2.12` you would need to either find a distribution that was already compiled with that version or compile your own distribution by hand. Sadly, the first one is discarded as I do not know any, and the second one is a really big and complex task. Also, in case you manage to get that running, you would still have another problem. Ensure all your libraries are compatible with **Scala** `2.12` most Spark libraries are not since the support of `2.12` is really new.

Comment: Finally, I would like to say that I also wanted to use **Scala** `2.12` on my last **Spark** experiment but it wasn't possible due the ecosystem being to slow to do the transition. However, that was 4 months ago, maybe things are better now?

Comment: Thank you Luis Miguel. I think compiling Spark against 2.12 is not a big deal, but the dependencies will indeed be a hassle. I will keep an eye on this. Stating support is officially deprecated on 2.11 while it is still widely used is a bit of an overstatement. Especially since it is the distribution that is provided on Databricks' platform (2.12 is not there yet). A bit of a conflicting statement here IMHO.